# While loops being ignored

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm trying to write a simple program which will take a number of inputs from the user and produce the max number (Highest number) min number (Lowest Number) and the average.

So far I have written the code but found that the second and third while loops were being ignored. I tested this by outputting println's. I'm new to Java but any help is appreciated :)

```
  public void analyseInput() {
    UI.clearText();

    UI.print("input (end with 'done')");           
    double sum = 0;
    double i=0;

    for( i=0; UI.hasNextDouble(); i++){                    //average
        double amt = UI.nextDouble();
        sum = (sum + amt);
    }

    UI.println("test0");

    int maxAge = 0;
    while(UI.hasNextDouble()){                              //max
        int age = UI.nextInt();
        while(age>maxAge){
            maxAge = age; 
            UI.println(maxAge);
        }
    }

    double minAge = 0;
    while(UI.hasNextDouble()){                              //min
        double age = UI.nextDouble();
        if(age<minAge){
            minAge = age;
        }
    }

    double average = sum/i;
    UI.nextLine();                                 // to clear out the input
    UI.println(average);
    UI.println(minAge);

}
```

Comment: The condition for your while loops is `UI.hasNextDouble()`. If there are no doubles left, this evaluates to false and it obviously won't enter the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Take out your for loop.

using it empties ui.doubles.

furthermore instead of iterating through your stack twice you might as well do the max, min and average calculations in one loop. also your max and finder isn't right, because it would only work on a sorted list and if the list was already sorted you would just look at either end of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the min age, max age, average for a set of data, instead of parsing over it a bunch of time, you can simply do it in one go.

```
public void analyseInput() {
    UI.clearText();

    UI.print("input (end with 'done')");           
    double sum = 0;
    double i=0;
    double maxAge = Double.MIN_VALUE, minAge = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    for( i=0; UI.hasNextDouble(); i++){                    //average
        double amt = UI.nextDouble();
        sum = (sum + amt);
        maxAge = Math.max(amt, maxAge);
        minAge = Math.min(amt, minAge);
    }

    double average = sum/i;
    UI.nextLine();                                 // to clear out the input
    UI.println(average);
    UI.println(minAge);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must to do all operations (max, min, avg) inside a single `while-loop` and initialize your variable right. To each new double value, update the min and max variable. Add to an accumulator all the values and calculate the average after the loop.